# Countable union of sigma algebra

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

I read from a book the below example that a countable union of sigma algebra's is not necessarily a sigma algebra.

I have problem understanding why N ∈ F Must mean N ∈ some Fi ? From the construction it seems that N belongs to F because of the limit, not any of the Fi...

Thanks

"Put Ωi = {j}j=1...i, and let Fi be the σ-algebra of the collection of all subsets of Ωi for i ∈ N. Suppose that F = ∪Fi (I=1... ∞ ) is also a σ-algebra. Since, for each i, {i} ∈ Fi and Fi ⊆ F we have {i} ∈ F. Thus, by our primary assumption, N = ∪{i} (I=1... ∞ ) ∈ F and, therefore, N ∈ Fi for some i, which implies N ⊆ Ωi , a contradiction. Hence, F is not a σ-algebra."

Comment: Reread the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions) of an infinite union of sets.  $x\in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ if and only if there is some $i$ such that $x\in A_i$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks! That's super clear.